# hyperledger explorer fails to start

Tags: hyperledger, explorer

Hyperledger explorer fails to start. Looks like it can't create the client for some reason. Maybe it can't read the client config and it replies client config undifined. This is the console logs file

```
******* Initialization started for hyperledger fabric platform ******, { 'network-1': 
   { version: '1.0',
     clients: { 'client-1': [Object] },
     channels: { mychannel: [Object] },
     organizations: { Org1MSP: [Object], Org2MSP: [Object], OrdererMSP: [Object] },
     peers: 
      { 'peer0.org1.example.com': [Object],
        'peer1.org1.example.com': [Object],
        'peer0.org2.example.com': [Object],
        'peer1.org2.example.com': [Object] },
     orderers: { 'orderer.example.com': [Object] } },
  'network-2': {} }
 client_configs.name  undefined  client_configs.profile  undefined
FabricUtils.createFabricClient 
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Error :  [ 'Invalid platform configuration, Please check the log' ]
Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
Closed out connections
```

Also at app.log it replies

```
[2019-08-21 09:35:23.018] [DEBUG] Platform - ******* Initialization started for hyperledger fabric platform ******
[2019-08-21 09:35:23.020] [DEBUG] Platform - Setting admin organization enrolment files
[2019-08-21 09:35:23.020] [DEBUG] FabricUtils - Organization [Org1MSP] enrolment files path defined as directory
[2019-08-21 09:35:23.021] [DEBUG] FabricUtils - Organization [Org2MSP] enrolment files path defined as directory
[2019-08-21 09:35:23.021] [DEBUG] FabricUtils - Organization [OrdererMSP] enrolment files path defined as directory
[2019-08-21 09:35:23.021] [DEBUG] Platform - Creating client [[object Object]] >>  undefined
[2019-08-21 09:35:23.022] [DEBUG] FabricUtils - ************ Initializing fabric client for [undefined]************
[2019-08-21 09:35:23.022] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Client configuration [undefined]  ...  this.client_config  { version: '1.0',
  clients: 
   { 'client-1': 
      { tlsEnable: true,
        organization: 'Org1MSP',
        channel: 'mychannel',
        credentialStore: [Object] } },
  channels: { mychannel: { peers: [Object], connection: [Object] } },
  organizations:
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue, but after looking into the steps as mentioned in Quick start (using docker) of https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer, it was the wrong config on docker-compose.yaml and test-network.json.

After modifying the config(refer below config), it works as expected :

All Files

[image]

**test-network.json**

```
{
"name": "test-network",
"version": "1.0.0",
"client": {
    "tlsEnable": true,
    "adminCredential": {
        "id": "exploreradmin",
        "password": "exploreradminpw"
    },
    "enableAuthentication": true,
    "organization": "Org1MSP",
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300"
            },
            "orderer": "300"
        }
    }
},
"channels": {
    "mychannel": {
        "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
        }
    }
},
"organizations": {
    "Org1MSP": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/e01e69598ae437dcbf5ea4f84f3b9164545ef245b84d157d7f659b47f5c3a26a_sk"
        },
        "peers": ["peer0.org1.example.com"],
        "signedCert": {
            "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem"
        }
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051"
    }
}
```

}

**docker-compose.yaml**

[image: docker-compose.yaml]

[image: explorer logs in docker dashboard]

Open Hyperledger Fabric Explorer on localhost:8080, and on login screen add below credentials :

```
"adminCredential": {
        "id": "exploreradmin",
        "password": "exploreradminpw"
    }
```

[image: hyperledegr fabric explorer]

**References :**

- https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer
- https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/main/README-CONFIG.md
- https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOT.md